# Best practice for using goto

Tags: c#, .net, goto

Is it right to use `goto` in this code? Are there any alternatives?

```
return ExecuteReader(cmd, reader =>
{
    List<BEPartnership> partnerhip = null;

    //Partnership
    if (!((SqlDataReader) reader).HasRows)
        goto exit;

    partnerhip = 
        new List<BEPartnership>{new BEPartnership().GetFromReader(reader)};

    //Customers
    if (!reader.NextResult() && !((SqlDataReader) reader).HasRows)
        goto exit;

    foreach (BEPartnership p in partnerhip)
        p.Partner = new BECustomer().GetFromReader(reader);

    //Contracts
    if (!reader.NextResult() && !((SqlDataReader) reader).HasRows)
        goto exit;

    List<BEContractB2B> contracts = new List<BEContractB2B>();
    contracts.Add(new BEContractB2B().GetFromReader(reader));
    // contracts = new BEContractB2B().GetFromReader2(reader).ToList();

    exit:
    return partnerhip;
});
```

Comment: The best practice is: DO NOT USE GOTO!

Comment: can't you do this with a Switch in a loop? I wouldn't say it is wrong as it does not really break the structure (goto belongs to unstructured languages) but I  think this can be done in a loop counting the steps maybe?

Comment: @Steven: that's an oversimplification

Comment: There are situations in which using goto is very useful.

Comment: There are situations in which using goto is very useless.

Comment: @Steven and @Flinsch: Well, if you take a look into .net framework source code you will see that Microsoft uses GOTO in number of places.

Comment: @Alex, @Henk: Show me one C# example were the use of the `goto` statement is  better than without it. The usefulness is imo limited to code generations were reading code is not an issue.

Comment: @HABJAN: Well, this might explain why Microsoft products have an unstable behavior sometimes. ;) Just a joke with a lot of truth in it. Honestly, you shouldn't take the code output of some Microsoft developers as a reference coding style.

Comment: @Steven The _only_ example I can imagine is using GOTO instead of a infinitely **recursive** loop, to avoid overflowing the stack. Even so one could probably, and should likely, rewrite the code to avoid GOTO.

Comment: Why not just "return partnership;" instead of goto?  Unless you've got some rigid coding standard that enforces one return per block.  I personally am a fan of "I'm done. GTFO!"

Comment: The only time the `goto` statement has been useful in C# is for jumping to another switch-case from a current one.  Even that could have been refactored if I really put the time and effort into it.

Comment: Every time you use "yield return" the compiler will put a goto into the compiled IL. We use goto all the time without even realising it!

Comment: @Mongus: Every time you make a loop the compiler puts a goto into the compiled IL. IL only has three basic control flows: throw, goto and return. Almost *everything* is goto. The point of structured programming is to choose control flows that are more *meaningful* than goto, not to avoid branching altogether.

Comment: Good point (I was just being facetious)

Answer (score 19):

You can replace each `goto exit;` with `return null;` or `return partnerhip;` if you wish to return the currently populated list.  (I assume a partnerhip is a cool partner?)

Answer (score 8):

I would say no.

I've been programming in C# since 2001 and have never used goto!

If you want a "short circuit" exit in your code, why not replace the

```
goto exit:
```

with

```
return partnership
```

Comment: Amen. Write short functions and you'll never need to `goto`.

Answer (score 5):

`goto` and "best practice" are mutually exclusive, in my opinion (and probably/hopefully in that of most others, too). The need for a `goto` indicates a faulty code design. In your case, the solution seems to be simple: I think you just have to replace `goto exit` by `return partnerhip` and to delete the label `exit:`. (Should it read "partnership" instead of "partnerhip"?)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing at the end is loading contracts from the reader if it is there. It reads much better if you make this intention explicit with a simple if statement.

Change the end to be :

```
if (reader.NextResult() || ((SqlDataReader) reader).HasRows)
{
    List<BEContractB2B> contracts = new List<BEContractB2B>();
    contracts.Add(new BEContractB2B().GetFromReader(reader));
}

return partnerhip;
```

Although it does appear you are just ignoring the contracts list... it isn't doing anything. Unless creating a new BEContractB2B class has some global side effects (bad news), you could just get rid of it alltogether..

Change the first goto to be

```
if (!((SqlDataReader) reader).HasRows)
    return null;
```

Since that is what you are doing, you should make it obvious you will return null.

Answer (score 1):

I found following case when goto could be a bit useful: [When To Use Goto When Programming in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/goto.html). But "**Never use GOTO**" was first thing I learned on University and so I really never used it (at least not in C,C++,C#,Java,...).

The biggest problem of GOTO is that if you read piece of method, you don't see from where it could be called. For example:

```
int a = 1;
division:
int b = 4 / a;
```

... sounds OK. But you wrote 0-dividing crash, if there is following GOTO after the division block:

```
int a = 1;
division:
int b = 4 / a;
// ... hundreds of lines ...
a = 0;
goto division;
```

... Or null-exception crash if there is GOTO before the division block:

```
goto division;
// ... hundreds of lines ...
int a = 1;
division:
int b = 4 / a;
```

... this is only one example, GOTO leads to much more disputable situations. So **please forget about GOTO and people (including you) will be happier during reading your code.**

Use "return partnership;" instead of your goto's.

Comment: Actually, your second example won't even compile. First of all, `a` is a value-type and can *never* be `null`. Second, the compiler will detect that `int a = 1;` is unreachable and first issue an unreachable code warning and then a use of unassigned local variable error which will cause the code to not compile.